# Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Procedure, Line 30 Error 50002, severity 10, state 1 was raised,

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

This is the execute section

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[SPM_GetBidderSupplier]
        @txtName = NULL,
        @txtPOBox = NULL,
        @txtAddress = NULL,
        @ddlCity = NULL,
        @txtDistrict = NULL,
        @ddlProvince = NULL,
        @txtPostalZC = NULL,
        @txtSupplier = NULL,
        @txtBidderID = NULL,
        @ddlStanding = NULL,
        @txtPartnerfunction = NULL,
        @txtParentSupplier = NULL,
        @ddlBidderStatus = NULL,
        @txtBidderNotes = NULL

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value
GO
```

This is the actual stored procedure

```
/*
Created By: Ace Nasir
Created Date: 19 August 2014
*/
--exec SPM_GetBidderSupplier

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPM_GetBidderSupplier]
   (@txtName varchar, 
    @txtPOBox varchar,
    @txtAddress varchar,
    @ddlCity varchar,
    @txtDistrict varchar,
    @ddlProvince varchar,
    @txtPostalZC varchar,
    @txtSupplier varchar,
    @txtBidderID varchar,
    @ddlStanding varchar,
    @txtPartnerfunction varchar,
    @txtParentSupplier varchar,
    @ddlBidderStatus varchar,
    @txtBidderNotes varchar)
AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    /*Check for valid parameter*/
    If LEN(@txtBidderID) =0  or  ISNULL(@txtBidderID,'') ='' 
    RAISERROR(50002,10, 1,'Error Accessing Bidder Record - Must Provide Bidder ID')
ELSE
    SELECT
       Supplier.Name1, 
       Supplier.Name2,
       Supplier.Name3,
       Supplier.Name4,
       Supplier.ID,
       Supplier.StreetAddress,
       Supplier.City,
       Supplier.ProvinceState
    FROM [dbo].Supplier
    WHERE   
        (Supplier.Name1 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.Name2 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.Name3 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.Name4 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.PoBox LIKE '%' + @txtPOBox + '%' OR @txtPOBox IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.StreetAddress LIKE '%' + @txtAddress + '%' OR @txtAddress IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.City LIKE '%' + @ddlCity + '%' OR @ddlCity IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.District LIKE '%' + @txtDistrict + '%' OR @txtDistrict IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.ProvinceState LIKE '%' + @ddlProvince + '%' OR @ddlProvince IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.PostalCodeZipCode LIKE '%' + @txtPostalZC + '%' OR @txtPostalZC IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.id LIKE '%' + @txtSupplier + '%' OR @txtSupplier IS NULL)
    AND (Supplier.notes LIKE '%' + @txtBidderNotes + '%' OR @txtBidderNotes IS NULL)

    UNION

    SELECT
       Bidder.Name1, 
       Bidder.Name2,
       Bidder.Name3,
       Bidder.Name4,
       Bidder.ID,
       Bidder.StreetAddress,
       Bidder.City,
       Bidder.ProvinceState
    FROM [dbo].Bidder
    WHERE   
    (Bidder.Name1 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.Name2 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.Name3 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.Name4 LIKE '%' + @txtName + '%' OR @txtName IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.PoBox LIKE '%' + @txtPOBox + '%' OR @txtPOBox IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.StreetAddress LIKE '%' + @txtAddress + '%' OR @txtAddress IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.City LIKE '%' + @ddlCity + '%' OR @ddlCity IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.District LIKE '%' + @txtDistrict + '%' OR @txtDistrict IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.ProvinceState LIKE '%' + @ddlProvince + '%' OR @ddlProvince IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.PostalCodeZipCode LIKE '%' + @txtPostalZC + '%' OR @txtPostalZC IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.Notes LIKE '%' + @txtBidderNotes + '%' OR @txtBidderNotes IS NULL)
    AND (Bidder.status LIKE '%' + @ddlBidderStatus + '%' OR @ddlBidderStatus IS NULL)
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error?

> Msg 18054, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SPM_GetBidderSupplier, Line 30
>   Error 50002, severity 10, state 1 was raised, but no message with that error number was found in sys.messages. If error is larger than 50000, make sure the user-defined message is added using sp_addmessage.

It doesn't make sense to me and according to a few blogs any severity before 10 is not really an error? Is this true? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: where's line 30 anyways?

Comment: Line 30 is the line after the stored procedure parameters are closed of with the bracket and the AS. AS is on 29.

Comment: Well, because your code says: `RAISERROR(50002` after checking the length of `@txtBidderID`. You must be explicitly calling the procedure with that parameter as `NULL`. Anyway stop declaring `varchar` without length - and if those are numbers make them numeric types and not strings. As it stands, when you pass in a `@txtBidderID` value of `'12345'`, it's going to look for `'1'`. Seriously. [Please read](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Answer (score 0):

The error is because of the line below obviously because you are passing the @txtBidderID as NULL -

```
/*Check for valid parameter*/
If LEN(@txtBidderID) =0  or  ISNULL(@txtBidderID,'') ='' 
RAISERROR(50002,10, 1,'Error Accessing Bidder Record - Must Provide Bidder ID')
```

Comment: Thanks. So blindly missed it. brain running on 20% today